# Requestors approving their own changes in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-repos

I am attempting to set up branch policies in Azure DevOps where the master branch is locked down from pushed other than Pull Requests. I have the following Branch Policies set:
[image]

However, I am still getting the following message on the PR when attempting to approve myself:

[image]

I believe based on the branch policy I should be able to approve that Pull Request. I found some issues online from a few years ago that apparently had a fix pushed to Azure DevOps. How can I approve my own change?

Comment: Hi Mike, Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer could solve this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I approve my own change?

The root cause of this question is the option: `When new changes are pushed: ->Require at least one approval on the last iteration`

You could change your branch policy: `When new changes are pushed: -> Reset all code reviewer votes`

[image]

Then you could approve your pull request and complete it successfully.

Comment: I spent an hour trying to figure the same thing out. The solution works but is totally unintuitive. Why can't I be the approver for 'Require at least one approval on the last iteration'? Otherwise make the text: 'Require an approval from a different approver on the last iteration'.